# Tkinter scale in realtime

Tags: python, linux, tkinter

By modifying some code that was present in one of the answers in Stackoverflow (sorry, i don't remember which one it is exactly), here is the code snippet.
I was trying to improve on it by using the `tkinter scale`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Tkinter import *
import threading

class MyTkApp(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()
    def callback(self):
       self.root.quit()
    def show_values(self):
       print self.s2.get()
       print self.s1.get()
    def run(self):
        self.root=Tk()
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.callback)
        self.s1 = Scale(self.root, from_=0, to=42, tickinterval=8)
    self.s1.set(19)
    self.s1.pack()
    self.s1.get()
    self.s2 = Scale(self.root, from_=0, to=200, length=600,tickinterval=10, orient=HORIZONTAL)
    self.s2.set(23)
    self.s2.pack()
    Button(self.root, text='Show', command=self.show_values).pack()
    self.root.mainloop()

app = MyTkApp()
print app.show_values()    
for a in range(0,10):
    print 'now can continue running code while mainloop runs'
```

I'm trying to get the values and return it to the rest of the mainloop in real time. 
How do we achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using thread, use callback (specify using `command` keyword arugment)

```
from Tkinter import *

def show_values(value=None):
    print s1.get(), s2.get()

root=Tk()
s1 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=42, tickinterval=8, command=show_values)
#                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
s1.set(19)
s1.pack()
s2 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=200, length=600, tickinterval=10, orient=HORIZONTAL,
           command=show_values) # <---
s2.set(23)
s2.pack()
Button(root, text='Show', command=show_values).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The callback is called when the value of the scale is changed.

---

**UPDATE**

```
from Tkinter import *
import time
import threading

class ScaleValue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.value1 = None
        self.value2 = None

def tkinter_loop(scale):
    root=Tk()
    s1 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=42, tickinterval=8, command=lambda v: setattr(scale, 'value1', v))
    s1.set(19)
    s1.pack()
    s2 = Scale(root, from_=0, to=200, length=600, tickinterval=10, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=lambda v: setattr(scale, 'value2', v))
    s2.set(23)
    s2.pack()
    root.mainloop()

scale = ScaleValue()
threading.Thread(target=tkinter_loop, args=(scale,)).start()

# ROP
while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    print scale.value1, scale.value2
```

Comment: The problem with callback is that the rest of the program can't continue execution till the `scale` is closed.

Comment: @pistal, How about running the **rest of the program** in thread ?

Comment: The `rest of the program` is already written without threading, and it doesn't look feasible to change that part. 
Found something here: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257045/trying-to-get-the-value-from-a-tkinter-scale-and-put-it-into-a-label`
Still figuring out how to implement it

Comment: What does **rest of the program** do?

Comment: Let us call `rest of the program` as `ROP`. It is trying to do some computation using data it gathers from various `performance counters` and `msr registers`. Sure, python is not the best way to go for efficiency. but it is the fastest for proof of concept (atleast for me).

Comment: Thank you!. I'm still learning threading and therefore it takes time to figure out.